# How to select a specific child element within div with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Say I have a  with multiple elements as such:

```
<div id="outermostdiv" >
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span>Random<a>SomeText</a></span>
</div>
```

How do I use a jquery selector to get to the "a" element's text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the context you've provided `$("#outermostdiv a").text()` should be sufficient.